# Consolidate Play Evolutions

Tags: playframework, playframework-evolutions

Since I have been preparing my Play! app for production and started backfilling the database, I have modified my models quite a bit. I am now up to 8.sql in my evolutions scripts and I was wondering if there was a way to consolidate these and start over at 1.sql.

Can I rewrite 1.sql to model my current schema and delete 2-8? Or will this cause Play to freak out?

It isn't a huge deal as I don't believe there is a limit on the number of evolutions scripts you can have, but it would be neater to have fewer. The reason I can't just delete my tables and start over is that I have data in there I would rather not delete.

I could probably back my data up and then reimport it except that I have spatial data (PostGIS) and I'm not sure if that would back up properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea since [the evolution script](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/Evolutions.scala) stores some metadata in your database (table `play_evolutions`), especially, it computes a [hash](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/Evolutions.scala#L34) against the SQL source code.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Create new consolidated evolution script with name: 1.sql

- Dump DB schema info, Use the # --- !Ups section
- Make sure to add schema, indexes, uniques, constraints (CREATE IF NOT EXIST)
- Make sure to add default records to DB (CREATE IGNORE)

2. Delete all previous evolutions from code repository (.sql files)
3. Commit changes
4. Manually truncate table play_evolutions from the database (using portforward / ssh / cli)
5. Push changes
6. Let your CI/CD pipepline run the evolutions
7. Make sure count(*) of play_evolutions table is 1

Congratulations, you have just squashed your evolution scripts.